# Problema como modelo JPA

Tags: java-ee, jpa

Tengo un modelo con 2 tablas, `Cuentas` y `Movimien`. Cuando se llama al método `merge()` de la tabla `Movimien`, intenta realizar un `insert` en la tabla `Cuentas`. No tengo claro si las relaciones las plantee correctamente. ¿Alguien me podría dar una mano con esto?

A continuación el modelo de la tabla `Movimien`, que al hacer el `update`
dispara el `insert` en la tabla `Cuenta`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movimien")
public class Movimien implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private Date fecha;
private short cuentaid;
private float importe;
private String concepto;

 @JoinColumn(name = "cuentaid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne
private Cuenta cuenta;

public Movimien() {
    this.cuenta = new Cuenta();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public short getCuentaid() {
    return cuentaid;
}

public void setCuentaid(short cuentaid) {
    this.cuentaid = cuentaid;
}

public float getImporte() {
    return importe;
}

public void setImporte(float importe) {
    this.importe = importe;
}

public String getConcepto() {
    return concepto;
}

public void setConcepto(String concepto) {
    this.concepto = concepto;
}

public Cuenta getCuenta() {
    return cuenta;
}

public void setCuenta(Cuenta cuenta) {
    this.cuenta = cuenta;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 53 * hash + this.id;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Movimien other = (Movimien) obj;
    if (this.id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}}
```

Y el modelo de la tabla `Cuenta`, a la que se le dispara el `insert` cuando se hace un `update` en la tabla `Movimien`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cuentas")
public class Cuenta implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String nombre;
private short tipo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="cuenta")  //Con mappedBy estamos indicando quién es el dueño de la relación.
private List<Movimien> movimien;

// Constructor - Requerido para lo EJB
public Cuenta() {
    this.nombre="";
    this.tipo = 0;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public short getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(short tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 97 * hash + this.id;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Cuenta other = (Cuenta) obj;
    if (this.id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}}
```

¿Alguna idea de cual puede ser el motivo de este comportamiento?

Comment: que es lo que esperas cuando haga el insert??? si lo tienes mapeado @OneToMany(mappedBy="cuenta")

Comment: Y como debe ser?, no tengo experiencia en JPA, pero de leer la documentacion, llegue a esa conclusion.

Comment: dejalo solo en cuentas así es la forma correcta

Comment: No funciona tampoco!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontre la solucion correcta, en la clase Movimien, reemplaze el siguiente codigo:

```
private short cuentaid;
...................
@JoinColumn(name = "cuentaid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne
private Cuenta cuenta;
```

por este:

```
//  private short cuentaid;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cuentaid", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Cuenta cuenta;
```

El problema era muy sutil.
espero que a otro le pueda resultar util!
Saludos